# Android database newbie. Error in running the application

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am a newbie to android application, and was trying one sample application given in this tutorial..
http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-and-sqlite-a-really-easy-tutorial-that-anyone-can-do/
I did exactly the same..and created a project in IDE and made the same package as in the tutorial. 
Here is my Main class code:

```
package com.jameselsey;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.demo.sql.R;

public class Main extends ListActivity
{

    private static String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "PERSONS_TABLE";
    private SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;
    private List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Cursor cursor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try
        {
            sampleDB = openOrCreateDatabase("NAME", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            createTable();
            insertData();
            lookupData();
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
        }
        catch (SQLiteException se)
        {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        }
        finally
        {

            if (sampleDB != null)
                sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
            sampleDB.close();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create a table if it doesn't already exist
     */
    private void createTable()
    {
       sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (PERSON_NAME VARCHAR, " +
                    "  COUNTRY VARCHAR, " +
                    "  AGE INT(3));");
    }

    /**
     * Insert some test data, modify as you see fit
     */
    private void insertData()
    {
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('James','ENGLAND',25);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('Dave','USA',18);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('Jean-Paul','FRANCE',33);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('Sergio','SPAIN',42);");
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME + " Values ('Hitori','JAPAN',73);");
    }

    /**
     * Run a query to get some data, then add it to a List and format as you require
     */
    private void lookupData()
    {
        cursor = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT PERSON_NAME, COUNTRY, AGE FROM " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " where AGE > 10 ", null);

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String personName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PERSON_NAME"));
                    String country = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COUNTRY"));
                    int age = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("AGE"));
                    results.add("" + personName + ", " + country + ", " + age);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and heres my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I got an error when I clicked on the application in the emulator. The error was

> Sorry, The application demosql
>   (process com.demo.sql) has stopped
>   unexpectedly. Please try again.

com.demo.sql is where the R.java file is.

Any ideas, why am i getting this error?!

thanks

**EDIT : 1**
oK, this is what i got from DDMS console:

```
[2011-04-08 17:30:44 - demosql] ------------------------------
[2011-04-08 17:30:44 - demosql] Android Launch!
[2011-04-08 17:30:44 - demosql] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-08 17:30:44 - demosql] Performing com.demo.sql.sqldemoo activity launch
[2011-04-08 17:30:44 - demosql] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-04-08 17:30:44 - demosql] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-04-08 17:30:46 - demosql] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-04-08 17:30:46 - demosql] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-04-08 17:31:32 - demosql] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-04-08 17:31:32 - demosql] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)
[2011-04-08 17:31:32 - demosql] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-04-08 17:31:32 - demosql] Uploading demosql.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-04-08 17:31:32 - demosql] Installing demosql.apk...
[2011-04-08 17:32:22 - demosql] Success!
[2011-04-08 17:32:22 - demosql] Starting activity com.demo.sql.sqldemoo on device emulator-5554
[2011-04-08 17:32:26 - demosql] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.demo.sql/.sqldemoo }
[2011-04-08 17:59:47 - demosql] ------------------------------
[2011-04-08 17:59:47 - demosql] Android Launch!
[2011-04-08 17:59:47 - demosql] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-08 17:59:47 - demosql] Performing com.demo.sql.sqldemoo activity launch
[2011-04-08 17:59:47 - demosql] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-04-08 17:59:47 - demosql] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-04-08 17:59:47 - demosql] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-04-08 17:59:47 - demosql] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-04-08 18:00:22 - demosql] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-04-08 18:00:22 - demosql] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2011-04-08 18:00:22 - demosql] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-04-08 18:00:22 - demosql] Uploading demosql.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-04-08 18:00:22 - demosql] Installing demosql.apk...
[2011-04-08 18:01:09 - demosql] Success!
[2011-04-08 18:01:09 - demosql] Starting activity com.demo.sql.sqldemoo on device emulator-5554
[2011-04-08 18:01:18 - demosql] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.demo.sql' on port 8645
[2011-04-08 18:02:18 - demosql] ------------------------------
[2011-04-08 18:02:18 - demosql] Android Launch!
[2011-04-08 18:02:18 - demosql] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-08 18:02:18 - demosql] Performing com.demo.sql.sqldemoo activity launch
[2011-04-08 18:02:18 - demosql] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2011-04-08 18:02:24 - demosql] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-04-08 18:02:24 - demosql] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2011-04-08 18:02:27 - demosql] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-04-08 18:02:27 - demosql] Starting activity com.demo.sql.sqldemoo on device emulator-5554
[2011-04-08 18:02:33 - demosql] ------------------------------
[2011-04-08 18:02:33 - demosql] Android Launch!
[2011-04-08 18:02:33 - demosql] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-08 18:02:33 - demosql] Performing com.demo.sql.sqldemoo activity launch
[2011-04-08 18:02:33 - demosql] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-04-08 18:02:33 - demosql] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-04-08 18:02:34 - demosql] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-04-08 18:02:34 - demosql] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

**EDIT - 2**
I created a new android project in eclipse, and that solved the problem. I think that in my previous project, I didnt edit the app name. But in new project everything is perfect. So, PROBLEM SOLVED. In any case, I am posting the logcat message here:

```
04-08 17:07:15.240: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
04-08 17:07:28.931: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
04-08 17:07:31.020: ERROR/BatteryService(67): usbOnlinePath not found
04-08 17:07:31.020: ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryVoltagePath not found
04-08 17:07:31.020: ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryTemperaturePath not found
04-08 17:07:31.060: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(67): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
04-08 17:07:39.851: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
04-08 17:07:39.851: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
04-08 17:07:40.071: ERROR/System(67): Failure starting core service
04-08 17:07:40.071: ERROR/System(67): java.lang.SecurityException
04-08 17:07:40.071: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
04-08 17:07:40.071: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
04-08 17:07:40.071: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
04-08 17:07:40.071: ERROR/System(67):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
04-08 17:07:41.941: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-08 17:07:41.941: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
04-08 17:07:41.951: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
04-08 17:07:41.951: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
04-08 17:07:41.961: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
04-08 17:07:46.070: ERROR/ThrottleService(67): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
04-08 17:07:47.550: ERROR/logwrapper(143): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
04-08 17:07:47.620: ERROR/logwrapper(147): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
04-08 17:07:47.720: ERROR/logwrapper(149): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
04-08 17:08:08.903: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(67): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
```

thank you so much guys.

Comment: If you're using eclipse, go to the DDMS view and post here the section of the log that's in red.

Comment: Posting the logcat would be helpful. go to command prompt and try this adb -s emulator-5554 shell and then logcat on the shell if u r using the emulator.

Comment: I am not able to find anything in DDMS perspecitve of eclipse. Nothing is there at all. Its complete blank.

Comment: Look at the Android -> LogCat view in Eclipse, and hit the "E" button to filter just "Error" level messages. If you have more than one device/emulator connected, you may have to open the Android -> Devices view and select which device you want to view logs for.

The LogCat view will print out stack traces on errors. Have you edited your Manifest file to include this activity?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the setContentView(R.layout.main). 
Your program will now run now.

The data of the database is displayed through setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results)).

Hope you now understand why setContentView(R.layout.main) need to delete.
Enjoy :)